# Why Wampmanager downloading speed is slow?

Tags: wamp

I've downloading wampserver for more than 5 hours and its 600mb. butdownloading speed goes as 50kb/s. if i donwloaded a movie or any other Software speed is above 800kb/s to 1mb/s.

Is there anyway i can download this fast?

I think this might be from my service provider issue. Dows anyone face the same issue?

[Screenshot of the download speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEnH0.png)

Tried searching for solution on google. didnt got any article regarding this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because of sourceforge.net servers. This issue is just not related to only Wampserver software...
I also faced the same issue earlier and others too...

Have a look at this thread and this might give you some idea of why it is slow:
https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/2310#issuecomment-1176585294